# Проблема с записью текста в текстовый файл

Tags: java

Есть такой фрагмент кода, направленный на то, что бы элемент записывался только в том случае, если такой же строки нету в текстовом файле

```java
for (WebElement i: elements) {
  x = 0;
  while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    if ((i.getText().substring(0, 30).replaceAll("\n", "").equals(sc.nextLine())) && (i.getText().length() >= 30)) {
      x = 1
      break
    }
  }
  if ((x == 0) && (i.getText().length() > 30)) {
    writer.write("\n${i.getText().substring(0, 30).replaceAll("\n", "")}");
  }
}
```

но он не работает, и все элементы в любом случае записываются. Укажите пожалуйста на проблему)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы на первом же элементе добегаете до конца файла, а потом на следующих итерациях у Вас `sc.hasNextLine() == false` и поиск по файлу не выполняется совсем.

Отдельный вопрос - зачем для каждого элемента читать весь файл?

```
// Строки файла
Set<String> lines = new HashSet<>();
// Читаем единоразово файл
while (sc.hasNextLine())
  lines.add(sc.nextLine());

// цикл по элементам
for (WebElement i : elements) {
  // получаем строковое представление
  String str = i.getText();
  if (str.length() > 30)) {
    // преобразовываем строку
    str = str.substring(0, 30).replaceAll("\n", "");
    // если такой строки нет в считанных строках файла, то записываем
    if (!lines.contains(str))
      writer.write("\n${str}");
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)